# Determining if system is consistent, and if it is determine if the solution is unique

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

In the following matrices [] is a nonzero entry and ∗ is a entry that may or may not be zero. For each of these (augmented) matrices determine if the associated system is consistent, and if it is consistent, determine if the solution is unique

[image]

a) **infinitely many solutions because** $x_1 = $ **any number?**

b) not sure

c) not sure

d) **inconsistent, no solution because 0 = 1** ( i think)

e) **infinitely many?**

Comment: Try writing out equations with variables, and then check what happens when * is a zero or a non-zero. i.e:

a.) x+y=0  $\rightarrow$ x=-y, 

set y=t and we get $x=-t, y=t$, therefore we have infinitely many solutions, like you said. If y is a zero, we get x=0, y=t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These matrices are augmented, which means the last column should be the numbers on the right side of the equation.
(a) Is consistent but not infinitely many solutions. Its equation would be $\blacksquare x_1=*, 0x_1=0$. So there should be only one solution.
 
(b) Is obviously inconsistent because $\blacksquare$ cannot be zero, but $0x_1$ will have to be zero.

(c) There should be only one unique solution, the first and second rows are obviously not the same with each other, so two useful equations for two unknown variables.

(d) inconsistent, similar to (b)

(e) You are right it is infinitely many solutions, because only two useful equations to solve for three unknown variables.

Comment: What? $x_1$ could be $1$ , thus $(1)(x_1) = *$(which may or may not be 0, I've chosen it to be 1) which means $x_1 = 1$ , the same would follow the rest of the set of real numbers so it would be infinite solutions no?

Comment: @Shammy You cannot switch $*$ as you wish. $\blacksquare$ and $*$ are both given numbers, they are not variables. So if you have a system with $1x_1=1$, there is only one solution for this system. $2x_1=1$ will be another system.