# Is this augmented matrix consistent? If so, is the solution unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following augmented matrices in which * denotes an arbitrary number and ◼️ denotes a nonzero number. Determine whether the given matrices are consistent. If consistent, is the solution unique?

[image: Matrix A]

[image: Matrix B]

These matrices are similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830072/determining-if-system-is-consistent-and-if-it-is-determine-if-the-solution-is-u), but I’m having trouble understanding the answers in that post and how they arrived at that answer. Any help understanding the setup here, as well as guidance on thinking through the solutions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding the written answers, my best piece of advice would be to try some explicit examples. Substitute non-zero numbers in for black squares, and other numbers in for the asterisks (make sure to try $0$ in there sometimes!). You don't have to solve each matrix, but see if you can figure out when there is a solution, when there isn't a solution, and when (if ever!) the solution is unique.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for the tips! A question about the ◼️ symbols versus the * symbols—is it reasonable to assume the squares are equal to 1? Meaning, they are pivot columns?

Comment: That's a good question. Remember, you are always allowed to divide any row by any non-zero number without changing the solutions. If you divide each row by the numbers in each black box, they will turn out to be $1$s.

Comment: @TheoBendit — so, in the second matrix, it looks like the solution is inconsistent? Because if ◼️ is a non-zero number, ◼️!= 0 (in the third row, specifically)?

Comment: The matrix is inconsistent, due to the third and fourth rows. Note, however, that neither the third nor the fourth row, in isolation, would tell you that the matrix is inconsistent necessarily.